# Magento 2 - Save custom shipping address' fields to quote_address table

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-address

I have did all the steps from [this tutorial](http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/) and it works well for updating custom fields in `quote` table.

In my case, I need to add custom fields to `quote_address` and (later) in `customer_address_entity` tables.

I've created a plugin for: 
`<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">`.

What I've got so far:

```
#Vendor/module/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php


public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
) {
    $this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, 'INDEXIS');

    $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();

    $number = $extAttributes->getNumber();
    $complement = $extAttributes->getComplement();
    $district = $extAttributes->getDistrict();
    $area_code = $extAttributes->getAreaCode();
    $this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, "number: " . $number);
    $this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, "complement: " . $complement);
    $this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, "district:" . $district);
    $this->logger->log(\Psr\Log\LogLevel::DEBUG, "area_code:" . $area_code);


    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

    $quote->setNumber($number);
    $quote->setComplement($complement);
    $quote->setDistrict($district);
    $quote->setAreaCode($area_code);
}
```

It logs the values in `debug.log` file but won't update the fields in my database.

I know that my mistake is trying to set my custom fields in `$this->quoteRepository`. So my question is: What object should I use to set my custom fields in `quote_address` table?

There will more questions related to this topic, but only after this one is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For address save, you need to assign value into address object. Here is an example:

**Here `delivery_date` is a new custom column of `quote_address` table**

```
$billingAddress = $addressInformation->getBillingAddress();
$billingAddress->setDeliveryDate('2016-09-30 12:22:00');
```

If you need to assign `shipping address` too, then you need to do it the same way. Basically magento uses two rows for addresses, in quote/order; One address for billing and one for shipping.

```
$shippingAddress = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setDeliveryDate('2016-09-30 12:22:00');
```

Comment: Awesome. I've set both addresses. Now, how can I show my custom data in payment screen? And how can I use the same form in payment screen (when the user unchecks "My billing and shipping address are the same")

Comment: It is saving in quote_address table but not showing in checkout shipping address

Comment: sadly, you almost need to make modification in every spot